# DB2 Union causes time out?

Tags: sql, performance, timeout, db2

First time working with DB2. I have a stored proc that performs a union, well it trys to anyhow. The procedure times out. The select statements on either side of the union execute quickly with no issue when done individually. Why would a union do this?

Here is some sudo code for the proc, assume data types are either int or string, and they match when compared or unioned unless otherwise noted in the SQL:

```
DECLARE Foo CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
  Select STRIP(A.Name) as my_Name, 
     Case A.Number
        when 2 then '(' || strip(char(A.Number)) || ')' strip(B.num)
        when 3 then '(' || strip(char(A.Number)) || ')' strip(C.num)
        when 4 then '(' || strip(char(A.Number)) || ')' strip(D.num)
        when 5 then '(' || strip(char(A.Number)) || ')' strip(E.num)
        when 6 then '(' || strip(char(A.Number)) || ')' strip(F.num)
        end as my_number
  FROM A
       left outer join B on A.Number= 2 and A.Name = B.Name
       left outer join C on A.Number= 3 and C.Name = B.Name
       left outer join D on A.Number= 4 and D.Name = B.Name
       left outer join E on A.Number= 5 and E.Name = B.Name
       left outer join F on A.Number= 6 and F.Name = B.Name 
      ,session.Temp_Result X
  WHERE X.ID = A.ID
  GROUP BY A.Number, A.Name, B.Name, C.Name, D.Name, E.Name, F.Name
for fetch only ur;

DROP TABLE Session.Temp_Result;

DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE session.Temp_Result
(     ID DECIMAL(18,0)
);

INSERT INTO session.Temp_Result
        select X.ID
        from Z, Y, X, Q
        where Z.num = 6
          and Z.ID = Y.ID2
          and Y.GROUPA = 'ABC'
          and Y.GROUPB = 'DEF'
          and Y.ID = X.ID2
          and X.ID = Q.ID            
        union
       select W.ID
        from Z, Y, W
        where Z.num = 6
          and Z.ID = Y.ID2
          and Y.GROUPA = 'ABC'
          and Y.GROUPB = 'DEF'
          and Y.ID = W.ID2
        group by ID;


  OPEN C_HIERARCHIES;
```

Comment: Please post the SELECT statement, as well as the type of each column involved.

Comment: Given that a `UNION` removes duplicates, I have a feeling that's part of the problem.  How many rows are being returned (by each statement), what are indices like, etc, may be useful information.

Comment: Each statement in returning approximately 5 IDs at this time. I can't get any index information till tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to query using "with" statement.

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE session.Temp_Result (
ID DECIMAL(18,0))
WITH REPLACE;

INSERT INTO session.Temp_Result
(ID)
WITH Q1(Y_ID)
AS (
SELECT Y.ID
FROM Z
    INNER JOIN Y ON Z.ID = Y.ID2
WHERE Z.NUM = 6 AND Y.GROUPA = 'ABC' AND Y.GROUPB = 'DEF')

SELECT X.ID
FROM X
    INNER JOIN Q1 ON X.ID2 = Q1.Y_ID
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Q WHERE Q.ID = X.ID)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT W.ID
FROM W
    INNER JOIN Q1 ON W.ID2 = Q1.Y_ID
```

If it does not help, try to use "Explain SQL" for the select statement. Maybe you should create some indexes...

Comment: It would be ideal if I could see how the tables have been indexed and modify them if nessecary, however that is not possible in the current enviroment.

Comment: The WITH REPLACE statement in the third line down causes an error in the stored procedure, however, with that removed this has improved the procedures execution and it no longer is timing out.

Comment: It makes sence to combine the duplicated portion of the two select statements and only perform this once, thats going to be more efficient. I'm  a little surprised that this fixes that time out though. Both select statements executed in less than a second individually. I assume this means becuase of the union, DB2 is using one select statement to filter results from the other as it executes the select

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the original code is missing a join condition that is present in the pseudocode.  You should rewrite the query using proper join syntax to verify the query.

In any case, if each subquery runs quickly and there is some perverse consequence of a union, can you try splitting it into two inserts:

```
INSERT INTO session.Temp_Result
    select X.ID
    from Z, Y, X, Q
    where Z.num = 6
      and Z.ID = Y.ID2
      and Y.GROUPA = 'ABC'
      and Y.GROUPB = 'DEF'
      and Y.ID = X.ID2
      and X.ID = Q.ID;

INSERT INTO session.Temp_Result
   select W.ID
    from Z, Y, W
    where Z.num = 6
      and Z.ID = Y.ID2
      and Y.GROUPA = 'ABC'
      and Y.GROUPB = 'DEF'
      and Y.ID = W.ID2
    group by ID;
```

Then you can query Temp_Result as:

```
select distinct id from TempResult
```

Removing duplicates seems unnecessary, since the data is so small, but you could also do that directly.